# Easticsearch reindexing multi-type parent/child index(v5.0) to join type index(v6.2)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-painless

I am reindexing my index data from ES 5.0(parent-child) to ES 6.2(Join type)

Data in index ES 5.0 is stored as parent-child documents in separate types and for reindex i have created new index/mapping based on 6.2 in my new cluster.

The parent documents flawlessly reindex to new index but the child documents throwing error as below

```
{
  "index": "index_two",
  "type": "_doc",
  "id": "AVpisCkMuwDYFnQZiFXl",
  "cause": {
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "[routing] is missing for join field [field_relationship]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

scripts i am using to reindex the data

```
  {
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://myescluster.com:9200",
      "socket_timeout": "1m",
      "connect_timeout": "20s"
    },
    "index": "index_two",
    "type": ["actions"],
    "size": 5000,
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {"term": {"client_id.raw": "cl14ous0ydao"}}
            ]
        }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index_two",
    "type": "_doc"
  },
  "script": {
    "params": {
        "jdata": {
            "name": "actions"
        }
    },
    "source": "ctx._routing=ctx._routing;ctx.remove('_parent');params.jdata.parent=ctx._source.user_id;ctx._source.field_relationship=params.jdata"
  }
}
```

I have passed the routing field in painless script as the documents are dynamic from source index.

Mapping of the destination index

```
{
  "index_two": {
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "template_actions": {
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "index": true,
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "date_detection": false,
        "properties": {
          "attributes": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        },
        "cl_other_params": {
          "type": "nested"
        },
        "cl_triggered_ts": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "cl_utm_params": {
          "type": "nested"
        },
        "end_ts": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "field_relationship": {
          "type": "join",
          "eager_global_ordinals": true,
          "relations": {
            "users": [
              "actions",
              "segments"
            ]
          }
        },
        "ip_address": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "processed_ts": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "processing_time": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "products": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "traits": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
          }
        },
        "segment_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "start_ts": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My sample source document

```
    {
    "_index": "index_two",
    "_type": "actions",
    "_id": "AVvKUYcceQCc2OyLKWZ9",
    "_score": 7.4023576,
    "_routing": "cl14ous0ydaob71ab2a1-837c-4904-a755-11e13410fb94",
    "_parent": "cl14ous0ydaob71ab2a1-837c-4904-a755-11e13410fb94",
    "_source": {
      "user_id": "cl14ous0ydaob71ab2a1-837c-4904-a755-11e13410fb94",
      "client_id": "cl14ous0ydao",
      "session_id": "CL-e0ec3941-6dad-4d2d-bc9b",
      "source": "betalist",
      "action": "pageview",
      "action_type": "pageview",
      "device": "Desktop",
      "ip_address": "49.35.14.224",
      "location": "20.7333 , 77",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "key": "url",
          "value": "https://www.google.com/",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "products": []
    }
  }
```

Comment: i end up using bulk api to transfer the data finally. No luck with the reindex api

Comment: mind sharing the bulk request? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and searching in elasticsearch discussions I found [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/an-routing-missing-exception-is-obtained-when-reindex-sets-the-routing-value/155140/2) that works:

`POST` *_reindex*

```
{
    "source": {
        "index": "old_index",
        "type": "actions"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "index_two"
    },
    "script": {
        "source": """

            ctx._type = "_doc";

            String  routingCode = ctx._source.user_id;
            Map join = new HashMap();
            join.put('name', 'actions');
            join.put('parent', routingCode);

            ctx._source.put('field_relationship', join);

            ctx._parent = null;

            ctx._routing = new StringBuffer(routingCode)"""
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :) .

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that routing is generally not required for a join field, however if you're creating the child before the parent is created, then you're going to face this problem.

It's advisable to re-index all the parents first then the children.